# Handle JSON object return null in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have to used JSON web Services for Login Validation, If Data become send is true then i catch it but How Can i handle if i get's null,  Is there any method to compare null object ?

my code is like this

```
  NSMutableDictionary *jons =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",jons);

NSMutableArray *rnameary = [jons  objectForKey:@"posts"];
NSLog(@" rname Arry is : %@",rnameary );

NSLog(@" Rname count is %d",[rnameary count]);

if([rnameary isEqual:[NSNull class]]) {
   NSLog(@"%d",[rnameary count]);
}
```

output if Valied user

```
2012-03-23 12:30:58.353 [1503:f803]  rname Arry is : (
    {
    IsDoctor = 1;
    PHCIDF = 3;
    UserIDP = 9;
    UserName = Manoj;
    isAdmin = 0;
}
```

)

output is invalied user

```
2012-03-23 12:29:40.944 [1481:f803]  rname Arry is : (
"<null>"
```

)

Comment: Try `if([rnameary isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])`

Comment: @ParthBhatt its also cant work!

Comment: Try `if([rnameary isEqual:[NSNull class]])`

Comment: @ParthBhatt no parth is also coud't work

Comment: Is `rnameary` an array for sure?

Comment: i can tell u one thing that my rnnameary is the type of posts ary

Comment: i will give u all code just a minitu

Answer (score 1):

If you could post JSON data it would be easier to identify problem, but my first guess is that object for key `"posts"` is not an array.

Comment: if i fetch valied username and pass then is's work

Comment: no, if i print josn dictionary than is's kind of post array the output is  posts =     (
        "<null>"
    );

Answer (score 1):

check this out(i think it should work):

```
if(rnameary){
     //your stuff here
}
```